# JSP: Página de item não Encontrado

Tags: java, jsp

Eu estou programando uma página para informar que o item pesquisado não foi encontrado.
Queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado e qual seria uma solução.

```
<c:forEach items="${proposta}" var="proposta">
            <div>
            <img src="..." alt="..." class="img-circle">
            <c:if test="${proposta.getTitulo() == 'null'}">
                <h1>Página não Encontrada</h1>
            </c:if>
            <br>
                <label>titulo:</label>
                <label>${proposta.getTitulo()}</label>
            <br>
                <label>subtitulo:</label>
                <label>${proposta.getSubtitulo()}</label>
            <br>
                <label>Necessidade:</label>
                <label>${proposta.getNecessidadeString()}</label>
            <br>
                <label>Area de Interesse :</label>
                <label>${proposta.getArea_interesseString()}</label>
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="proposta?id=${proposta.getId_proposta()}">Exibir proposta </a>
            <br>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Porque está fazendo um foreach? Tente explicar melhor a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Deve ser indicado em `items` o bean e o método, sem o `get` no início, que retorna a lista de propostas, exemplo:

`items="${managedBean.listaDePropostas}"`.

Para mostrar o resultado não precisa fazer uso do `get` e nem dos parênteses basta `${proposta.titulo}`.

Comment: tem q exporta uma biblioteca JSTL Function
e depois chamar a função length
<c:when test="${fn:length(proposta) == 0 }">
     <h3>Não foi Encontrado item com essa chave</h3>
    </c:when>